# How can I simplify this this code [VBA]

Tags: ms-access, vba

My current code

```
    With PT.PivotFields("Year")
         .PivotItems("2012").Visible = False
         .PivotItems("2013").Visible = False
         .PivotItems("2014").Visible = False
         .PivotItems("2011").Visible = False
         .PivotItems("2015").Visible = False
    End With
```

is there a way to set a variable = to the current year so that I can use an If/Then statement to format this pivot table instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this works

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem


Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
' change field as needed
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Year")

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    If pf.Value <> "2016" Then pi.Visible = False
Next pi
```

Comment: `For Each` loops are even nicer.... but you're reading OP's mind here, the question didn't mention anything about "hide all but the current year" ...or I misread it. Anyway, well done.

Comment: Ooooh oops O_o I guess i was taking it further than necessary

Comment: I also didnt realize this was for Access and not Excel.... But easily changed to account for that

Comment: That makes two of us =)

Comment: Thanks this for each loop is really helpful but again I have the same question I asked @Mat's

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use `For` loops.

```
With PT.PivotFields("Year")
    For yr = 2011 To 2015
        .PivotItems(CStr(yr)).Visible = False
    Next
End With
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking and I think my question is worded wrongly. the Pivot field has years from 2008-2020. Is there a way to set yr to the current year so that I don't need to update the macro next year when its 2017?

Comment: @sorenthomsen well you know how to declare a variable, don't you? Doug's answer has 3 examples of *object variables*. Values are exactly the same, except you'll do `Dim value As Integer` and assign it without the `Set` keyword.

Comment: No. I said **without** the `Set` keyword, so `Dim yr As Integer : yr = Year(Date)`, which would assign `yr` the value of the current calendar year. The `Set` keyword is only necessary when assigning **object references**.

Comment: I only want to deselect year values that are less than the current years. does this look correct?
        Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Year ")
        yr = Year(Now)
 
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            If pf.Value < "yr" Then pi.Visible = False
        Next pi

Comment: Don't put the `yr` variable in quotes in the `pf.Value < "yr"` expression; the quotes make it evaluate as a *string literal*, which will not give you the results you're expecting. Otherwise, well you could boil it down to `pi.Visible = pf.Value >= yr`